# TYPO3 Extension [NITSAN] Ultimate FAQ Error

Tags: html, web, typo3

I installed that extension using the TYPO3 backend. When I try to open the extension TYPO3 shows me an error.

> #1257246929 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\View\Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
> Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->index" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/ns_faq/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/NoConstant.html). No paths configured.

How can that be? There is nothing in the manual that says there is more to do after the install.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to include the TypoScript from that extension. Please check the "Include static (from extensions)" part of your TypoScript template.